# Laravel: Layered Authentication ("Remember Me")

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I've been working on a "single sign on" framework for a company so that they can consolidate four copies of their employee database into one on their intranet server. I've got the functionality almost complete, but then I ran into one requirement problem.

When they go to https://secure.example.com, they want everything behind authentication and they MUST HAVE "remember me" functionality which is no problem. However,  when they go to https://supersecure.example.com they want to force the user to "reauthenticate" for this single session.

I suppose it is also worth noting that https://supersecure.example.com and https://secure.example.com are two separate laravel projects.

A comparable example would be your phone making you type in your password every time you opened the store app.

TL;DR How do I disallow Auth::viaRemember() on specific routes?

Comment: If you're using a single sign on, where are you storing the remember_token?

Comment: https://github.com/mpociot/reauthenticate or https://github.com/pascalschwientek/laravel-reauth might give you some ideas

Comment: I'm not aware of any abstract solution. It all depends on how you've implemented the single sign on feature. If you're sharing a session then just have a flag saying "reauthenticated" and set it to false while on `secure.example.com` and when going to `supersecure.example.com` you can check and if it's false call `Auth::logout()` and redirect to login again (and then set the flag to true if you're logging in supsersecure.example.com` but again, this depends on how you're implementing things.

Comment: The remember_token is in the users table. Ben, it looks like both of those are just using middleware to set flags in a session just like apokryfos recommended, so I might just go that route. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: I'm a little confused on your SSO then, are you using a shared database between all the projects?

Comment: @Devon All the projects are using a shared users database.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is something like OAUth2 server.  May be check in to www.okta.com that will give you all the build in functionality for achieving this. Or alternatively write your own Authorization server and integrate your own custom api in Laravel 5. Google and Facebook also provide this type of SDK.